# How do I source the NAME attribute of a custom netsuite record type?

Tags: netsuite

I want to create a source list/from that brings in the name of the sourced record. However, this isn't exposed to me. Is there a switch somewhere that allows "name" to be available like my custom fields?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the preferences their is a switch to turn on Internal IDs. From there you can click on a label on the form and the little help popup will have the id of the field.

In this case it was.....  "name"